# Python/Selenium make script go back to loop if input fails and try again

Tags: python, html, selenium, loops, web-scraping

I coded a "bot" that cliks on a button - but it is not as simple as that.

Once the bot clicks on the button, a second one appears and the bot clicks on it, but then a timer sets in and the "first " button is still there but not the second one (this one will appear again when the timer stops). I want the code to continue executing the process of clicking both buttons even if there is the timer and the program cant find the second's button path. (The code as it loops back, looks for the second button but doesn't find it, it therefore prints out an error:)

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\fkahd\PycharmProjects\bot\bot.py", line 19, in <module>
    submit2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div[6]/div/div/div[1]/div/form/button").click()
  File "C:\Users\fkahd\PycharmProjects\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1244, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\fkahd\PycharmProjects\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\fkahd\PycharmProjects\bot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[4]/div[6]/div/div/div[1]/div/form/button"}
  (Session info: chrome=98.0.4758.82)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x01067AC3+2587331]
    Ordinal0 [0x00FFADD1+2141649]
    Ordinal0 [0x00EF3BB8+1063864]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F201CE+1245646]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F203CB+1246155]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F4A612+1418770]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F386D4+1345236]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F48A0A+1411594]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F384A6+1344678]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F153F6+1201142]
    Ordinal0 [0x00F162E6+1204966]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0120DF22+1680738]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x012C0DBC+2413564]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x010FD151+563089]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x010FBF13+558419]
    Ordinal0 [0x0100081E+2164766]
    Ordinal0 [0x01005508+2184456]
    Ordinal0 [0x01005650+2184784]
    Ordinal0 [0x0100F5BC+2225596]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x771FFA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77357A9E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77357A6E+238]


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I therefore coded an exeption, with `try:` and `except:` so it goes back to the homepage and navigates back to the button if there is an error but then the code stops - But i want it to stay in the loop and continue trying to click the buttons.

If you are more advanced, is there any way to read the timer and try again once it hits a certain value ? Timer HTML:

```
    <div id="c2VuZC9mb2xsb3dlcnNfdGlrdG9s">
<script type="text/javascript">
clearInterval(cltimer);
var et88e8a9cbc190762b = 420
function updatetimer() {
var ogqsbud75e2aaab9a29662 = Math.round((et88e8a9cbc190762b - 30)/60);
var lzrdp0381a = et88e8a9cbc190762b % 60;
if (lzrdp0381a < 10) {
lzrdp0381a = '0' + lzrdp0381a; 
}
$('#aqzcfpledc4ad').html('Please wait ' + ogqsbud75e2aaab9a29662 + ' minute(s) ' + lzrdp0381a + ' seconds for your next submit!');
if (et88e8a9cbc190762b <= 0) {
clearInterval(cltimer);
$('#aqzcfpledc4ad').html('Next Submit: READY....!');
} else {
et88e8a9cbc190762b--; 
}
}
var cltimer = setInterval('updatetimer()', 1000);
</script>
<h4 style="text-align:center;color:#337ab7;font-weight:bold;font-size:115%;" id="aqzcfpledc4ad">Please wait 6 minute(s) 53 seconds for your next submit!</h4></div>
```

Here is my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

link = 'xxx'

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://zefoy.com/")

time.sleep(5)

share = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[5]/div/button").click()
paste = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div[6]/div/form/div/input")
paste.send_keys(link,Keys.RETURN)
submit = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div[6]/div/form/div/div/button").click()

time.sleep(1)

submit2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div[6]/div/div/div[1]/div/form/button").click()

try:
    while True:
        submit = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div[6]/div/form/div/div/button").click()
        time.sleep(1)
        submit2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div[6]/div/div/div[1]/div/form/button").click()
        time.sleep(10)
except:
    driver.back()
    share = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[5]/div/button").click()
    paste = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div[6]/div/form/div/input")
    paste.send_keys(link, Keys.RETURN)
#make code go back to loop
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I figured out: read the `#` for more explanation

```py
# import web interface modules:

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

# sleep module to make script wait while website loads

from time import sleep


# Link chromedriver to the script (chromedriver enables the interface)

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

# get the website by the url

driver.get("https://zefoy.com/")

# take an input

vidUrl = input("url: ")

# I figured out that we can use a function as a loop

def loop1():
    global i
    sleep(10)

# I also used a try/except loop so the code doesn't exit and prints an error but continues on

    try:
# There is a captcha at the beginning that the user has to solve

        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[5]/div/button").click()
    except:
        print("Solve Captcha!, Refreshing...")
        driver.refresh() #refreshing if captcha doesn't get solved to avoid being stuck
        loop1()

# Interacting with the web interface using another try/except loop

    try: 
        sleep(2)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div[6]/div/form/div/input").send_keys(vidUrl)
        sleep(1)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div[6]/div/form/div/div/button").click()
        sleep(1)
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[4]/div[6]/div/div/div[1]/div/form/button").click()
        sleep(2)
        driver.refresh()
        i += 1
        total = i * 500
        print("Success delivered!")
        sleep(5)
        loop1()
    except: 
# if the upper part fails then the script is going to execute this section

        print("Timer still running, trying again in a minute")

# driver.refresh resets the web interface:

        driver.refresh() 
        sleep(5)
# we make the script refresh and wait for the page to load 
# loops brings the code back to the loop
        loop1() 

# input to start the bot 
bot = int(input("Type 1 to start\n"))


if bot == 1:
    print('starting engine...')
    loop1()
else:
    print('error')
```